# Identity component of $\mathrm{Ker}(E^n→E^m)$ in the advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, short-exact-sequences

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ker{Ker}$Silverman's "Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves", p.115 reads $$0\to\mathfrak{a}^{-1}Λ\to\Bbb{C}\to\Ker(E^n\to E^m)\to Λ^n/A^tΛ^m\quad (1)$$ is exact implies that
$\Bbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}^{-1}Λ$ is the identity component of $\Ker(E^n→E^m)$, because $Λ^n/A^tΛ^m$ is discrete and $\Bbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}^{-1}Λ$ is connected with respect to complex topology.

I think once all map in the exact sequence (1) is proved to be continuous with respect to complex topology, it is understandable argument, but I think it takes nontrivial argument to prove that.

How can I prove (1)'s maps are continuous with respect to complex topology ? (or some other point of view avoid topological argument?)

Comment: For which map in the diagram that produced this sequence through the snake lemma are you worried that it is not continuous?

Comment: I think every map has no appriori reason to be continuous with respect to complex topology.

Comment: If we admit all maps in  $R_K^m→R_K^n→\mathfrak{a}→0$ and $0→Λ→\Bbb{C}→E→0$ is continuous, the diagram before snake lemma consist of all continuous maps, but even if I admit first two sequence consist of continuous maps, I worry connecting homomorphism is also continuous.

Comment: Prop 4 in https://nyjm.albany.edu/j/1999/5-11.pdf shows that the snake map is continuous. Then you only need that $0\to\Lambda\to\mathbb{C}\to E\to 0$ is formed by continuous maps and the topology is the quotient topology. That is clear from the definition.

Comment: Oh, that's I needed. Thank you very much. But in your pdf, I think continuity of three maps $Λ^n→Λ^m$, $ \Bbb{C}→\Bbb{C}$, $E^n→E^m$ given by $A^t$ is what we need. I don't get why continuity of all maps in $Λ→\Bbb{C}→E$ ensures this. Indeed how can I prove these threee maps are continuous ?

Comment: Oh course, the multiplication by a matrix is continuous, right?